# Sort an array of arrays by key

Tags: javascript, arrays

My apologises if this has been answered before, searching a wide array of possible terms but couldn't find the answer I was looking for.

I have an array, sales = [], and sales are adding in via a a loop

```
for(var i=0; i<json.sales.length; i++) {
 sales[parseFloat(json.sales[i][0])] = parseFloat(json.sales[i][1])
}
```

Appreciate any input

Array output:

```
[ '0.00000979': 1730,
  '0.00000969': 206,
  '0.00000955': 3141,
  '0.00000951': 525,
  '0.00000941': 159,
  '0.0000095': 1000,
]
```

Expected out

```
[ '0.00000979': 1730,
  '0.00000969': 206,
  '0.00000955': 3141,
  '0.00000951': 525,
  '0.0000095': 1000,
  '0.00000941': 159,
]
```

Comment: show us the array you have and what is the expected output also?

Comment: That is an invalid object. It is not an array. You should get a syntax error if that is there on your page.

Comment: Thats not an array, thats a JS object (aka hash, map, associative array...). Objects in js don't have order, and can't be sorted.

Comment: @Vatev That's not an object either. Objects are wrapped in the curly braces `{` and `}`.

Comment: Well.. it is an "object attempt" I guess...

Comment: I think the `[ ]` are supposed to be `{` and `}`. however, you should have a look at the lodash (https://lodash.com/docs)  library.

Comment: Sorry guys, it was not a push the method is updated with the actual code above

Comment: In that case, my previous comment still stands - you can't sort it, because it doesn't have internal order. You need to use an actual array `[]`, with indexes 0,1,2,3..., `push` items into it, and then sort that.

Comment: Ok looks like I'll need to restructure the entire thing, do you recommend a array of structs or an array of arrays for things like sorting and picking out a specific price without searching

Comment: You can have the same objects in multiple structures if needed. However it's difficult to imagine a case when one would need a direct lookup by exact price. You can also do a binary search in the sorted array, although I doubt you will need to.

Comment: Thanks @Vatev you been great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This in invalid syntax, you are **mixing array and object** syntax:

```
[ '0.00000979': 1730,
  '0.00000969': 206,
  '0.00000955': 3141,
  '0.00000951': 525,
  '0.00000941': 159,
  '0.0000095': 1000,
]
```

To be able to sort, you need a valid array, actually an **array of arrays**:

```js
var data = [ 
  [0.00000979, 1730],
  [0.00000969, 206],
  [0.00000955, 3141],
  [0.00000951, 525],
  [0.00000941, 159],
  [0.0000095, 1000]
]

var sortedData = data.sort((a, b)=>a[0] < b[0]);
console.log(sortedData)
```

Check the documentation of the [sort() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort)

Comment: Thank you will change up and use this method